# Need help matching a two list that are nested list or two dimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I have two lists that are two dimensional lists. Is there a way to match all rows from df1 with rows from df2?

If so can this be done without using a loop?

Comment: What do you mean by `match`? What are `df1` and `df2`? Could you show a small example of the starting values, the exact desired result, and explain briefly how it should be calculated?

Comment: i have two list that are two dimensional or nested list df1=[[13, 14, 23],
 [6, 10, 15, 25],
 [5, 9, 19, 25],
 [17, 20, 21, 25],
 [11, 13, 22, 25]]

df2=[[7, 8, 15, 16, 21],
 [9, 11, 12, 17, 21],
 [5, 14, 16, 17, 21],
 [2, 10, 14, 18, 21],
 [6, 8, 17, 18, 21]]
i would like my result to be 0 [[], [], [14], [14], []]
1 [[15], [], [], [10], [6]]
2 [[], [9], [5], [], []]
3 [[21], [17, 21], [17, 21], [21], [17, 21]]
4 [[], [11], [], [], []]

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by "match" to check if they contain same items then simply use `==` operator if they have the same order
for example, if I have

```
a = [[1,3], [2,4], [7,9], [8, 10]]
b = [[1,3], [2,4], [7,9], [8, 11]]
```

then:

```
a == b
output: false
```

but

```
a = [[1,3], [2,4], [7,9], [8, 10]]
b = [[1,3], [2,4], [7,9], [8, 10]]
output: true
```

if the two lists are unordered then you can do `sorted(a) == sorted(b)`
However, this won't work if for example `a = [[2,1],[4,3]]` and b = `[[1,2],[3,4]]`

Here you should implement a method that sorts 2d list which won't be that hard